# react web app blank page sometimes when i reload, and when i do a change and i reload again it comes back, same cycle

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i have a react web app and its behaving strangely, so when i load the web app through this url http://localhost:3000/ it loads a blank page, if i go to the code and i make even a comment and save and refresh the site comes back again, but this is persistent on the root url as stated http://localhost:3000/, my rooter switch i think its pretty fine but you can check it below here.

```
<Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={DefaultPage} />
      <Route path="/initialshopspage" component={InititalPage} />
      <Route path="/login/:type" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/reset" component={Reset} />
      <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
</Switch>
```

so i want always when i load the route url, it should go to {DefaultPage} component

Comment: Try placing this statement as last statement inside switch:
`<Route exact path="/" component={DefaultPage} />`

Comment: i did it and problem still exists

Comment: Could you reproduce the problem [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ufjxgz)?

Comment: @PrãtéékThápá i arranged the files as you stated in the stacklitz and it works sir, thank,